# controller behavior is chocking my api request to my method

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components, yii2-basic-app

I have login method and I want to allow access to it for authentication. But when I add behavior to my class, it throws some garbage errors.

here is my controller

```
namespace api\controllers;

use common\models\User;
use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;
use common\models\Authentication;

class AuthenticationController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Authentication';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'except' => ['login'],
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBasicAuth::className(),
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                QueryParamAuth::className(),
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {

        $access_token = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

found the issue

HttpBearerAuth::className(),

was missing use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;

thanks